# Controlling Codebase registry entries in heat-generated WiX fragments

Tags: wix, gac, heat

I have a .NET 4.0 assembly that needs to be made COM-visible during installation. I'm using WiX (version 3.5), so generating a WiX fragment with heat is the logical option. This works fine, except no matter how I twiddle the knobs on heat, the CodeBase RegistryValues default to "file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/..." while the assembly is most certainly not installed in that directory.

The registry entries are added correctly during installation, but point to a non-existent assembly. Sad day. I have this issue even in the simplest possible use case ("heat asm.dll -out asm.wxs").

The options seem to be:

- Handle installation of the assembly elsewhere in the WiX project, then manually modify the CodeBase declarations in the fragment before passing it to the rest of the WiX toolchain.
- Manually add an Assembly=".net" attribute to the file tag
  (http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/net-COM-registration-with-heat-td3606182.html)
- Transform the fragment with XSLT ([2010-06-03 Accentient Blog “Adding HEAT output to the GAC”](https://accentient.com/blog/adding-heat-output-to-the-gac))

None of these options are particularly appealing. Is there an automated way to do this that doesn't involve fiddling with XSLT?

Comment: The codebase registry values in the generated wxs from heat indicate that the values will be expanded to the path the file is installed to on the target machine.  By default, the generated wxs file will also contain a Directory element for the file being harvested.  What does the generated wxs file look like?  Can you also post a link to the msi log file during installation?

Answer (score 0):

Does registration-free COM activation meet your requirements?

Registration-Free Activation of COM Components: A Walkthrough
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

Comment: Interesting link, thanks. I have worked around the issue by manually editing the heat-generated fragments. The number of assemblies I had to register was small enough to make this feasible.